# Reading Regular Expression in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm able to read and download list of .jpg files on a page using this regular expression

```
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(htmlText,@"http://.*?\b.jpg\b", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Output example:  http://somefiles.jpg from this line
`<img src="http://somefiles.jpg"/>` in html
**Question**:How could I read files in this kind of format?

```
<a href="download/datavoila-setup.exe" id="button_download" title="Download your copy of DataVoila!" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/download/datavoila-setup.exe')"></a>
```

I just want to extract files with  .exe on the page. So on the example above ^ I just want to get the `datavoila-setup.exe` file. Sorry I'm a little noob and confuse how to do it T_T. Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me. :)

**this is my updated codes but I'm getting error on the HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); part "No Source Available" and I'm getting an null value for list :(**

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the url given by the user
            string urls;
            urls = txtSiteAddress.Text;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            //Give request to the url given 
            HttpWebRequest requesters = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urls);
            requesters.UserAgent = "";

            //Check for the web response
            WebResponse response = requesters.GetResponse();
            Stream streams = response.GetResponseStream();

            //reads the url as html codes
            StreamReader readers = new StreamReader(streams);
            string htmlTexts = readers.ReadToEnd();

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(streams);
            var list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                         .Select(p => p.Attributes["href"].Value)
                         .Where(x => x.EndsWith("exe"))
                         .ToList();
           doc.Save("list");
           }
```

this is Flipbed answer it works but not I'm not getting a clean catch :( I think there is something to edit on splitting the html to text

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the url given by the user
            string urls;
            urls = txtSiteAddress.Text;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            //Give request to the url given 
            HttpWebRequest requesters = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urls);
            requesters.UserAgent = "";

            //Check for the web response
            WebResponse response = requesters.GetResponse();
            Stream streams = response.GetResponseStream();

            //reads the url as html codes
            StreamReader readers = new StreamReader(streams);
            string htmlTexts = readers.ReadToEnd();

            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            string checkurl = webclient.DownloadString(urls);

            List<string> list = new List<string>();//!3

            //Splits the html into with \ into texts
            string[] parts = htmlTexts.Split(new string[] { "\"" },//!3
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);//!3

            //Compares the split text with valid file extension
            foreach (string part in parts)//!3
            {
                if (part.EndsWith(".exe"))//!3
                {
                    list.Add(part);//!3

                    //Download the data into a Byte array
                    byte[] fileData = webclient.DownloadData(this.txtSiteAddress.Text + '/' + part);//!6

                    //Create FileStream that will write the byte array to
                    FileStream file =//!6
                            File.Create(this.txtDownloadPath.Text + "\\" + list);//!6

                    //Write the full byte array to the file
                    file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);//!6

                    //Download message complete
                    lblMessage.Text = "Download Complete!";

                    //Clears the textfields content
                    txtSiteAddress.Text = "";
                    txtDownloadPath.Text = "";

                    //Close the file so other processes can access it
                    file.Close();
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: I would use [FizzlerEx](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/) the  you can just use a[href$='exe'] syntax to get all elements in the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer but too long for a comment. (I'll delete it later)

To resolve the issue *it works, it doesn't work etc*; a complete code, for those who may want to check

```
string html = @"<a href=""download/datavoila-setup.exe"" id=""button_download"" title=""Download your copy of DataVoila!"" onclick=""pageTracker._trackPageview('/download/datavoila-setup.exe')""></a>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);


//Anirudh's Solution
var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a//@href")//get all hrefs
                .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                .Where(x => x.EndsWith("exe"))
                .ToList();
//returns empty list 


//correct one      
var itemList2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]") 
                 .Select(p => p.Attributes["href"].Value)
                 .Where(x => x.EndsWith("exe"))
                 .ToList();
 //returns download/datavoila-setup.exe
```

Comment: @Anirudh then what does this mean *I have tested it in LINQPAD..it works* ?

Comment: i tested and dumped the output..what I was seeing was the output of anchor's inner text not of href.in hurry i assumed it to be href's but never looked to the fact that I was looking for href's

Comment: Nice catch. I still prefer FizzlerEx syntax though :-p

Comment: actually I like this approach on catching but I'm getting an error "No Source Available" on  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); line any idea why? :(

Comment: and I'm getting a null value for the itemList2. :(

Comment: @bot just copy all the code above and try it again. I works. I can only test it with the info you provided.

Comment: please see how I do it on my updated question. I can't figure out what's the problem there. :(

Comment: @bot you use `doc.Load` **after** you read the stream with `ReadToEnd`, You should use `doc.LoadHtml(htmlTexts)` instead.

Comment: @I4V thanks for the catch the doc was now able to load the htmltext.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilitypack](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/&ei=v7KdUfzkOMvOrQfRyIHgBQ&usg=AFQjCNG2MH29eft1y8OrwFMjVzPNbVc0-w&sig2=W9SAiRdXINx6x3d8ggiALA&bvm=bv.46865395,d.bmk)

You can use this code to retrieve all exe's using HtmlAgilityPack

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://yourWebSite.com");

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")//get all hrefs
                  .Select(p => p.Attributes["href"].Value)
                  .Where(x=>x.EndsWith("exe"))
                  .ToList();
```

`itemList` now contain all exe's

Comment: **1)** `SelectNodes("//a//@href")` selects `a`s not `href`s **2)** `.Select(p => p.InnerText.EndsWith("exe"))` selects a boolean variable so you have a boolean list.

Comment: @I4V corrected..thanks..but the 1st part is correct..it would select hrefs..am not using //a[@href] xpath

Comment: @Anirudh See the name `SelectNodes`. It select `nodes` not attributes. Don't trust your mind, check it.

Comment: @Anirudh I should? I tested your code with the html fragment in the question. And it doesn't work as i expected.

Comment: I'm getting a null value on the itemlist any idea why? :(

Comment: @bot you should use `HtmlWeb` class of HtmlAgilityPack..see the edited ans

Answer (score 1):

I would use [FizzlerEx](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/), it adds jQuery like syntax to HTMLAgilityPack. Use the `ends-with` selector to test the href attribute:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;

var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load("http://example.com/page.html")
var page = document.DocumentNode;

foreach(var item in page.QuerySelectorAll("a[href$='exe']"))
{
    var file = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

And an explanation of why it is bad to parse HTML with RegEx: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expressions you could just use normal code.

```
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        string[] parts = htmlText.Split(new string[]{"\""},                
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            if (part.EndsWith(".exe"))
                files.Add(part);
        }
```

In this case you would have all the found files in the files list.

## EDIT:

You could do:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
string[] hrefs = htmlText.Split(new string[]{"href=\""},                
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string href in hrefs)
{
     string[] possibleFile = href.Split(new string[]{"\""}, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     if (possibleFile.Length() > 0 && possibleFile[0].EndsWith(".exe"))
         files.Add(possibleFile[0]);
}
```

This would also check that the exe file is within a href.

Comment: I have to add though, this solution does not need any external libraries.

Comment: `I just want to extract files with .exe on the page` - would suggest there are an unknown number of elements. This assumes you have retrieved the elements.

Comment: actually I also tried your code and it works. the only problem is that its not that clean catch compare to the above answers. could you simplify the htmlText.split with href like above? If you could do it maybe i could change my mind and choose this as the answer. thanks. :)